# Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

Installed FFMPEG with codecs. 
Which codecs are necessary to run this code the right way ?

```
ffmpeg -i 'tmp/INSTAVID_7hER3y.mp4' -c:v copy -an -dn -sn -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_format mp4 'tmp/videosegments.mp4'  2>&1
```

I get error on this.
This is the Error Log

Error Log:
https://pastebin.com/ePpdhM3D

Comment: Your build is very old. Upgrade to at least 4.0 and try.

Comment: As the above comment but also.... I wish you (and other people) would state your operating system when showing FFMPEG commands. Different systems have a slightly different syntax.